# What is this integration "method" name?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functions

I see that people often write this equality:

$$\int\limits_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int\limits_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f(x)\,\mathrm df(x)$$

when dealing with functins in general, that is when something is trying to be proven.

Why this equality holds? Is this substitution method and if it is what was substituted? If not, which one is it?

Comment: Are you sure it's not $\int_a^bf(x)d(f(x))=\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}udu$ (where $u=f(x)$)?

Comment: @mjh That is what I have concluded from my EE lectures. I also have [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/982825/understanding-integration-and-substitution) question related to this one.

Answer (score 0):

This is called: [Integration by Substitution.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution)

It is a consequence of the [Chain Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) for the derivative of the composition of functions.